# I want to pass the instance of one form to another form. How can I do that?

Tags: python, django, object, view, model

For eg: I have booking form and I have passenger form. I have one to one relationship with Booking model and Passenger model. Now I am on booking form, and when I click "book this flight" I am routed to passenger form. Now at that time, I want to pass the instance of booking form to passenger form. IN the following code, I am putting instance of booking form in passenger form which doesnt work. Can someone help??

```
def bookpassenger(request,pk):
            obj = Booking.objects.get(id=pk)
            content = {
                'form': PassengerForm(instance= obj)
                # 'items': Booking.objects.get(id=pk)
    
            }
    
            return render(request, 'booking/passenger.html', content)
```

This is the view after i submit the passenger form.

```
def bookpassengersubmit(request):
    # if request.method == 'POST':
        form = PassengerForm(request.POST or None)

        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            print('we are good')
        messages.success(request, 'Successfully added')
        return redirect('booking')

    # else:
    #         messages.error(request, 'Submit again')
    #         return redirect('bookpassengersubmit')
```

Comment: You add a `pk` value in the url and view, and also fetch the instance in the form.

Comment: Often both the rendering of the form, and submitting (the POST request) are simply handled by the same view. This is often better since logic that is the same can be shared, and because all the logic is in the same function, it is easy to extend form (both in rendering and submitting).

Comment: Yes, the thing is while rendering the passenger form, i need to pass the pk , but while submitting the passenger form, i dont need to submit pk...That is why i used two views. A

Comment: Please help with this .